# How to use the old Wireshark interface?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I download Wireshark 2.0 and it has a new interface. The [Release Notes 2.0](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/wireshark-2.0.0.html) say:

> Wireshark 2.0 features a completely new user interface which should provide a smoother, faster user experience. The new interface should be familiar to current users of Wireshark but provide a faster workflow for many tasks...

I'm actually finding the opposite. I can't even start a trace because the start screen only allows me to select an old trace (and the drop down is empty because there are none). None of the other widgets or buttons are active (for example, clicking on *Ethernet en0* does nothing):

[image]

The Release Notes also fail to tell us how to go back to the old interface. How do I do back to the Wireshark 1.x interface?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to go back to the old interface, but you can configure the capture interfaces on this screen by clicking "Capture options" in the main toolbar.

Comment: Just found out that in Windows, there's "Wireshark" (with the new interface) and "Wireshark Legacy" (with the old interface). Maybe it's the same in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Did you single-click en0 or double-click it? You should be able to start a capture from the main window by selecting one or more interfaces and one of

- Double-clicking on the interface(s)
- Pressing the "start" button (blue fin) in the toolbar.
- Selecting Capture → Start.

If one or more of those doesn't work then that's a bug which should be reported.

If you *really* want to use the old UI you can install version 1.12 or install the GTK+ variants of the homebrew or MacPorts packages.